# Bulk copying files in C++ Windows 8 Store app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I have a Windows 8 Store app written using C++/CX in which I need to copy multiple files (in one shot) from a user-selected location to the App's localdata folder.

In Windows Runtime, I find only StorageFile::CopyAsync API which allows me to copy one file at a time.  I do it this way:

```
task<IVectorView<StorageFile^>^>(openPicker->PickMultipleFilesAsync()).then([this](IVectorView<StorageFile^>^ fileVector)
{
    m_copyTasks.clear();

    for (auto file : fileVector)
    {
        m_copyTasks.push_back(create_task(file->CopyAsync(ApplicationData::Current->TemporaryFolder, file->Name, NameCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)));
    }

    when_all(begin(m_copyTasks), end(m_copyTasks)).then([this](std::vector<StorageFile^> results)
    {
        for (auto copiedFile : results)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }).then([this]()
    {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

Is there a better alternative that doesn't force me to create a separate task for every file bur rather allows me to copy the user-selected filevector in one go?

Comment: No, I don't think there is. Other developers have been coding similar solutions to yours in C# as well.

Comment: If that helps there is a `Windows.Storage.BulkAccess` namespace: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.bulkaccess.aspx

Comment: @user2720372 That looks like a read-only set of operations for just getting some bulk information about files and folders